# Why loop is running once?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()

{
    int num;
    char another="y";
    for(;another=="y";)
    {
        printf("no. is ");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        printf("sq. of %d is %d", num,num*num);
        printf("\nWant to enter another no. : y/n");
        scanf("%c", &another);
    }
}
```

I have C code like this. According to me, this should work like: Enter the no and give square. But its nor running in infinite loop. But it is running only once. Why?

I am using GCC4.8.1  compiler on windows 64 bit.

Comment: I suggest you turn on compiler warnings (or turn up the level). `char another="y";` isn't valid.

Comment: `"y"` --> `'y'`, `"%c"` --> `" %c"`

Comment: Also, for this kind of question, either run it in a debugger or add a printf() statement after the scanf() to see what the contents of `another` are as you come through the loop. This really isn't difficult stuff.

Comment: strcmp() instead of equality

Comment: @EdHeal [Why ?](http://ideone.com/g1kpen)

Comment: `char another="y";` assigning a string to a character

Answer (score 2):

Because on second iteration `scanf` assign `\n` to `another`instead of assigning `y`.

**EXPLANATION:** When you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key after typing the input, then one more character goes to the buffer along with the typed input. This character is produced by <kbd>Enter</kbd> and is `\n`. Suppose you typed `y` and then pressed the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key then the buffer would contain `y\n`, i.e, two characters, `y` and `\n`.
When `scanf("%d", &num);` is executed then it reads the number typed in and leaves behind the `\n` character in the buffer for next call of `scanf`. This `\n` is read by the next `scanf` call `scanf("%c", &another);` irrespective of what you have  typed in your console.

To eat up this new line `char`, use a space before `%c` specifier in `scanf`.

```
scanf(" %c", &another); 
       ^Notice the space before %c.
```

And change

```
for(;another=="y";) {...}  // Remove the double quote.
```

to

```
for(;another=='y';) {...}   // Single quote is used for `char`s.
```

Comment: Please explain. I'm newbie

Comment: @user3207558; Is it better now? Do you need more information?

Answer (score 0):

The test in the loop is wrong:

```
another=="y"
```

this compares the value of `another`, a single character, with the value of a string literal, which will be reprented as a pointer to the character `y`. It should be:

```
another == 'y'
```

You should have gotten compiler warnings for this, since it's very strange to compare a small integer with a pointer.